# Ues cross function in openrefine with jython

Tags: jython, openrefine

Can I use the cross function ( https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Other-Functions#crosscell-c-string-projectname-string-columnname ) with jython language  in openrefine (googlerefine 2.5)

Answer (score 0):

if you download the new version (2.6), you can do it directly by GUI (in column menu --> edit column --> add column(s) from other projects)